# SQL Update query with condition from a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I need to update a column in a table based on other tables.

```
SELECT        
    StockItem.ItemID, StockItem.Code, StockItem.AverageBuyingPrice, 
    MovementBalance.CostPrice, ProductGroup.CostingMethodID, 
    CostingMethod.CostingMethodName
FROM
    StockItem 
INNER JOIN
    MovementBalance ON StockItem.ItemID = MovementBalance.ItemID 
INNER JOIN
    ProductGroup ON StockItem.ProductGroupID = ProductGroup.ProductGroupID 
INNER JOIN
    CostingMethod ON ProductGroup.CostingMethodID = CostingMethod.CostingMethodID
```

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is to set

```
MovementBalance.CostPrice = StockItem.AverageBuyingPrice
```

where `CostingMethod.CostingMethodID = 2`.

I'm struggling with the `CostingMethod` as it comes from a different table.

Could someone help me out?

Many thanks

Comment: You seem to know the filter that needs to be applied so not understanding your struggle..do you have a specific issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE MovementBalance
SET CostPrice = StockItem.AverageBuyingPrice
FROM StockItem 
INNER JOIN MovementBalance ON StockItem.ItemID = MovementBalance.ItemID 
INNER JOIN ProductGroup ON StockItem.ProductGroupID = ProductGroup.ProductGroupID 
INNER JOIN CostingMethod ON ProductGroup.CostingMethodID = 
CostingMethod.CostingMethodID
WHERE CostingMethod.CostingMethodID = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption since you've tagged *Sql server Management Studio* you're using SQL Server, the following would appear to be what you are asking for. Note the use of table aliases makes for a more compact and readable query:

```
update mb 
  set mb.CostPrice = si. AverageBuyPrice
from StockItem si
join MovementBalance mb ON mb.ItemID = si.ItemID
join ProductGroup pg on pg.ProductGroupID = si.ProductGroupID
join CostingMethod cm ON  cm.CostingMethodID = pg.CostingMethodID
where cm.CostingMethodId = 2;
```